# Typescript Array.filter return type

Tags: arrays, typescript

```
let _fiveElems: [Value, Value, Value, Value, Value]
let _threeElems: [Value, Value, Value]
_threeElems = _fiveElems.filter( // some code that will filter down to three elements )
```

How can I avoid getting this compiler error?:

> Type 'Value[]' is not assignable to type '[Value, Value, Value]'.

I can set the type of `_threeElems` to `Value[]`, but I know it will return three elements so it doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function that checks the array length and does an unsafe cast at runtime:

```
function safeArrayCast<T>(arr: T[]) : [T, T, T]{
  if (arr.length !== 3) {
    throw new Error("Array is not length of 3");
  }
  return <any>arr;
}

let _fiveElems: [Value, Value, Value, Value, Value];

let _threeElems: [Value, Value, Value];

_threeElems = safeArrayCast(_fiveElems.filter(predicate));
```

Or, if you are **REALLY** sure that the filter will return 3 elements, you can cut that extra check:

```
_threeElems = <any>_fiveElems.filter(predicate);
```

But remember, using these unsafe casts will basically break your typesafety!

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is strongly typed and your knowledge about returning value does not actually matter. `filter` can return variable length array in general thus you must comply and assign its return value to the variable of type `Value[]`.
During indexing array you can do whatever you want to, so if you are sure that there are 3 elements you can assign them to the `_threeElems` array.

Strongly typing is actually the thing that many people love TypeScript for.